# How do you get entries from a Derby database that were inserted during the last 30 seconds?

Tags: java, database, eclipse, derby

I'm brand new to Derby (and basically databases in general) and am trying to get my feet wet with Derby via Eclipse using Java.

What I'm trying to do is generate a report of all entries currently in the Derby database from the last 30 seconds since the report has been generated.

I managed to get what I wanted in MySQL with the following:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > (now() - interval 30 second)

Is there an equivalent or similar functionality in Derby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Derby does not support standard (ANSI) SQL date arithmetics. You need to use the JDBC escape functions:

```
c:\db-derby-10.8.2.2\bin>ij
ij version 10.8
ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:c:/temp/sotest';
ij> create table foo (datetime timestamp);
0 rows inserted/updated/deleted
ij> insert into foo values (current_timestamp);
1 row inserted/updated/deleted
ij> commit;
ij> select *
from foo
where datetime > {fn timestampadd(SQL_TSI_DAY, -10, current_timestamp)};
> > DATETIME
-----------------------------
2012-06-10 12:32:48.859

1 row selected
ij>
```

For a complete list of functions see the Reference Manual: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefjdbc88908.html

Comment: I actually tried using this command earlier but I kept getting the following error: INTEGER is an invalid type for argument number 2 of TIMESTAMPDIFF.

Comment: @Stephen: it works for me. You will need to show us the code that produces that error (and please include the definition of the table)

Comment: Sure thing, here it is: SELECT * FROM app.user_count WHERE datetime > {fn timestampdiff(SQL_TSI_SECOND, -30, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)};

Comment: @Stephen: as I said: that exact statement works for me (See my edit). There is clearly something you are not telling us.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it does look like it works for you.  Not sure why it won't work for me, but here's my output when I type it in:
http://pastebin.com/88fa3Nt3

Comment: @Stephen: you are using `timestampdiff` but you should use `timestampadd` as I have done in my answer

Comment: Oops, missed that.  Sorry, I'm running on 26 hours here.  That slight fix made it work precisely as I wanted, thanks for the help!